# jQuery <dt> events are not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following jQuery 3.x script in a separate .js file linked to from a page which definitely contains the relevant HTML elements:

```
$(function() {

    var titleShow = 'Click to show', titleHide = 'Click to hide', showHideDefLists = $('div.show-hide-def-list');

    showHideDefLists.find('h3').addClass('hidden').attr('title', titleShow);
    showHideDefLists.find('dl').hide();

    showHideDefLists.on('click', 'h3', function () {
        var heading = $(this);

        if( heading.hasClass('hidden') ) {
            heading.removeClass('hidden');
            heading.addClass('shown');

            heading.next('dl').slideDown(function() {
                heading.attr('title', titleHide);
            });
        } else {
            heading.next('dl').slideUp(function() {
                heading.removeClass('shown');
                heading.addClass('hidden');
                heading.attr('title', titleShow);
            });
        }
    });

    showHideDefLists.on('hover', 'dt', function () {
        var dt = $(this);

        if( $.isNumeric(dt.data('time')) ) {
            if( dt.hasClass('hover') ) {
                dt.removeClass('hover');
                dt.next('dd').removeClass('hover');
            } else {
                dt.addClass('hover');
                dt.next('dd').addClass('hover');
            }
        }
    });

    showHideDefLists.on('click', 'dt', function () {
        var dt = $(this);

        if( $.isNumeric(dt.data('time')) ) {
            document.getElementById('media-player').currentTime = dt.data('time');
        }
    });

});
```

And here is example HTML:

```
<main role="main">
    <h2>Example</h2>
    <video id="media-player" src="/example.mp4" width="720" height="480" controls preload autoplay></video>
    <p id="media-caption">Some words.</p>
    <div id="media-chapters" class="show-hide-def-list">
        <h3>Chapter List</h3>
        <dl>
            <dt data-time="0">Chapter 1</dt><dd>0:00</dd>
            <dt data-time="124">Chapter 2</dt><dd>2:04</dd>
            <dt data-time="223">Chapter 3</dt><dd>3:43</dd>
            <dt data-time="349">Chapter 4</dt><dd>5:49</dd>
            <dt data-time="410">Chapter 5</dt><dd>6:50</dd>
            <dt data-time="445">Chapter 6</dt><dd>7:25</dd>
            <dt data-time="541">Chapter 7</dt><dd>9:01</dd>
            <dt data-time="588">Chapter 8</dt><dd>9:48</dd>
            <dt data-time="607">Chapter 9</dt><dd>10:07</dd>
        </dl>
    </div>
</main>
```

The idea is to add the `.hover` class to both the `<dt>` and its matching `<dd>` when *hovering* over the `<dt>` (but only if the `<dt>` has a `data-time` attribute with a number), and then navigate `#media-player` (a `<video>` element pointing to an .mp4 file) to the time point in said `data-time` attribute when *clicking* on said `<dt>`.

An earlier version of this script (paired with an earlier version of jQuery) worked perfectly using the same HTML. Now after updating it only the `<h3>` click event (for showing/hiding the definition lists) works. What gives?

I've successfully determined that the callback functions for the two `<dt>` events do not get called at all. Furthermore, moving them inside the callback for `.slideDown()` (within the `<h3>` click event) doesn't change anything.

I've also checked to make sure that the `<dt>` elements are actually selectable by modifying the script to change all their text to "test". So how come I can do that, but attaching events to the same `<dt>` elements does not work?

UPDATE: Using `showHideDefLists.find('dt').hover(function () {code});` and `showHideDefLists.find('dt').click(function () {});` (i.e. using the shortcut functions instead of on()) works as expected, so it must have something to do with on() I guess?

Comment: Please add the relevant HTML and CSS to your question and place the code into a "code snippet" while you are editing.

Comment: I don't think the HTML and CSS _is_ relevant, since all you need to know is that `showHideDefLists.find('dt')` returns a non-empty resultset (as evidenced by my stated test of changing the text for these same <dt> elements) and that all hiding/showing is done here in my script, not in the CSS. And I apologize but I don't know what you mean by "place the code into a "code snippet" while you are editing."

Comment: You may not think that the HTML and CSS are relevant, but they generally are and adding it makes it easier for us to understand what you are doing and provide you with an answer. That's why we ask that questions have the relevant code with them. Often times the OP is mistaken in their approach or in the code that they felt wasn't relevant. And, when you are editing your question, click the `<>` button on the edit tool bar, which let's you insert your code into a "code snippet", which is a runtime environment that let's us actually run your code.

Comment: Well at this point I'm just curious as to why a shorthand event function (e.g. .click()) would work and .on() not work. That said, I'm fine using the shorthand functions, so it's not really worth going to all the trouble that you're asking for :-)

Comment: Even JQuery recommends against the short-hand functions and recommends `.on()`. But, do as you will. I'm just trying to help you understand how to get help here at SO.

Comment: I know I've heard that in the past, but the current API page for the .click() shorthand (http://api.jquery.com/click/) doesn't say not to use it. Anyway, there must be some implementation difference between the two in order for one to work and the other to not work.

Comment: The [documentation for `.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) says *The .on() method attaches event handlers to the currently selected set of elements in the jQuery object. As of jQuery 1.7, the .on() method provides all functionality required for attaching event handlers. For help in converting from older jQuery event methods, see .bind(),  .delegate(), and .live(). To remove events bound with .on(), see .off(). To attach an event that runs only once and then removes itself, see .one()*

Comment: And, if one method is working and the other isn't, it is likely that the issue could be the element itself, which is why we ask to see the related HTML and CSS.

Comment: Yeah, I read through that page when my code stopped working, but it doesn't explain why it would work for a descendant `<h3>` element and not for a descendant `<dt>` element, nor why .click() and .hover() work fine when it does not.